# Methods for drug intake/delivery

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

My world is largely based around the production and consumption of 'drugs', chemicals which have physiological affects. Given the variety of drugs in the world, I am looking for alternate ways of consuming them. There are the standard ways, of course: smoking, snorting, suppositories, oral consumption.

I am looking for more 'creative' ways of drug intake, with the reasons for why they must be taken this way.

Ex: eye drops. Reason: the chemical is too potent to be swallowed/dropped on the tongue, so absorbing it through the eyes is slow enough to avoid the negative affects of an overdose which would come from the rapid oral absorption to be used at all.

Ex: skin patches. Reason: the chemical is produced on a certain sort of material as a catalyst and cannot be separated from it after the fact, requiring the use of cutting the material into strips and placing on the skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is pretty much idea generation but it is acceptable enough for me to give it a try, so here is a list in order of realism;

- Injection- This one is pretty obvious, use needles with the drug in them and inject them into your skin. The higher the pressure in the vein the more effective it will be.
- Spray- Similar to mace spray or perfume a spray would be an unusual, unique but still realistic way of ingestion.
- Connections- As the brain is simply a complex biological computer, by adding electrodes as suggested by @SJuan76 you could make the brain forcefully release pleasure chemicals.
- Exposure- If the drug is an emanating force like radiation (but of course less deadly) just simply being around it would affect people.
- Transplants- If the drug cannot be extracted from its natural source and that source comes from an animal, then (as ridiculous as it would be) transplants would allow for a high.
- Tattoos- Finally, to have a high while double tasking, add the drug to the ink while you're getting a tattoo.

Comment: Add connection: you put some electrodes on your head and precisely calibrated currents cause the drug effect. Or increase it with a "direct-to-brain" jack.

Comment: @SJuan76 good idea